# Python GTK3: how to use gtk_*_new_*() functions

Tags: python, gtk3

In GTK3, how can I use `gtk_*_new_*()` constructors?

For instance, consider:

```
GtkWidget * gtk_recent_chooser_menu_new_for_manager ()
```

How can I use it?

I am trying to port a PyGTK2 program, and I can workaround things like `gtk_text_view_new_with_buffer()` by instead doing:

```
view = Gtk.TextView()
view.set_buffer(buffer)
```

Is it possible to use such functions directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr**: Use the Python constructor normal form to set construction properties instead of the convenience C API.

The various `_new` constructors in the C API, including the basic `_new()` one, are just wrappers around `g_object_new()`. Constructors like `type_new_with_foo()` are just convenience functions for C developers to give some type safety around a call to `g_object_new()` and property setting; so, for instance, `gtk_recent_chooser_menu_new()` is just:

```
return g_object_new (GTK_TYPE_RECENT_CHOOSER_MENU, NULL);
```

and `gtk_recent_chooser_menu_new_for_manager()` is:

```
return g_object_new (GTK_TYPE_RECENT_CHOOSER_MENU,
                     "recent-manager", manager,
                     NULL);
```

i.e. a way to set the (constructor-only) "recent-manager" property.

The Python bindings do not call the C API for constructing objects; the Python constructor normal form, e.g.:

```
button = Gtk.Button()
```

is the equivalent of calling `g_object_new(GTK_TYPE_BUTTON, NULL)`. The constructor normal form accepts arguments, in the form of a dictionary of property names and values:

```
button = Gtk.Button(label='Hello, world')
```

This is the equivalent of calling `gtk_button_new_with_label()` in C. The Python bindings layer will provide all the necessary type safety at run time.

It's usually recommended to use this approach, and **not** calling the C API because:

- it's more Pythonic, as it follows the conventions of the language
- it's more flexible, as it lets you set more properties without requiring additional C API

Comment: That was a superb description of the constructors in bindings. Meanwhile, I open the following related question. Do you think you can help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38171196/python-gtk3-how-to-create-a-gtk-filechoosedialog

Answer (score 1):

I figure it out.

Apparently you can just use things like:

```
view = Gtk.TextView.new_with_buffer(buffer)
```

Interestingly, `Gtk.TextView.new() == Gtk.TextView()`

Comment: I don't know if Python requires those functions. The constructor (`*new()`) should be doing extra work but perhaps the binding handles that anyway.  C, C++, etc. however require these functions, because you create a `GtkWidget` and then instantiate it with the constructor. On the other hand, you have typeless languages like Perl, where you use the functions to differentiate between different types of widgets.

Comment: @oldtechaa In Python, `Gtk.Button()` is the same as `Gtk.Button.new()`. If you want to use a custom `new_*()` you should reference it directly. [reference needed -- but I don't remember where I found this hehe]

Comment: Sounds like the binding handles it for you. That's a pretty good binding then. It spoils Python people though not to need their constructors. :) Perl, on the other hand, sticks close to the C style except for typing, but also is a good easy binding.

Comment: @oldtechaa GTK+ has many flaws, but, indeed, the bindings are pretty cool.