# Python GTK3: how to create a Gtk.FileChooseDialog?

Tags: python, gtk3

How to create a Gtk.FileChooseDialog properly?

[This popular tutorial](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dialogs.html#id2) says to use code like the following:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

dialog = Gtk.FileChooserDialog("Please choose a folder", None,
    Gtk.FileChooserAction.SELECT_FOLDER,
    (Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
     "Select", Gtk.ResponseType.OK))
```

But, if you run this with `python -W error` (to catch the deprecated warnings) it says:

```
  File "test3.py", line 8, in <module>
    "Select", Gtk.ResponseType.OK))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/__init__.py", line 287, in new_init
    category, stacklevel=stacklevel)
gi.overrides.Gtk.PyGTKDeprecationWarning: Using positional arguments with the GObject constructor has been deprecated. Please specify keyword(s) for "title, parent, action, buttons" or use a class specific constructor. See: https://wiki.gnome.org/PyGObject/InitializerDeprecations
```

Using `Gtk.FileChooserDialog.new` gives `TypeError: Dialog constructor cannot be used to create instances of a subclass FileChooserDialog`.

[The API](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/FileChooserDialog.html) says nothing about the constructor. Weird.

ps: The answer to this question should work with `python -W error`. It should not rely on deprecated APIs. It is the all point of me asking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply follow out the instructions and use keyword arguments.  I also changed the buttons to using `.add_buttons()` since that also threw a DeprecationWarning:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

dialog = Gtk.FileChooserDialog(
    title="Please choose a folder",
    action=Gtk.FileChooserAction.SELECT_FOLDER,
)

dialog.add_buttons(Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
                   "Select", Gtk.ResponseType.OK)
```

Comment: Where do you find the documentation please ? I could not find anything

Comment: @Mike I haven't worked with Gtk in a few years, but when I did I used the reference [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/). It's not designed for the Python language, but it's almost all the same structure. I've just now found [this](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0) that's written for Python that looks very useful, but I've never used it myself. For a general tutorial if you're getting started, I used [this](https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

Comment: I've finally found the same as the last one you gave, [more precisely here](https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dialogs.html#filechooserdialog). Thank you !